# Selecting next submit after actual textarea and disable it

Tags: jquery

I have various instances of a form in a page. I want to desactivate the submit button of that ones with the default text in the textarea. My actual code is:

```
// This works
$(".proposal-write-comment-submit").each(function(){
    var element = $(this).closest(".proposal-write-comment-textarea");

    var default_text = element.attr("data-default");
    var value_text   = element.val();

    if(default_text == value_text) {
        $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");    
    }
});

// This no
$(".proposal-write-comment-textarea").keypress(function(e){
    var default_text = $(this).attr("data-default");
    var value_text   = $(this).val();

    if(default_text == value_text) {
        $(this).closest(".proposal-write-comment-submit").attr("disabled","disabled");  
    } else {
        $(this).closest(".proposal-write-comment-submit").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

My HTML code:

```
<form class="proposal-write-comment" method="post" action="">
    <textarea class="proposal-write-comment-textarea" data-default="Write a comment...">Write a comment...</textarea>
    <input class="proposal-write-comment-submit" type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

The second part of the javascript doesn't works. How I can select right the submit buttons "next to" the textarea?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the '[siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)' selector -

```
if(default_text == value_text) {
        $(this).siblings(".proposal-write-comment-submit").attr("disabled","disabled");  
    } else {
        $(this).siblings(".proposal-write-comment-submit").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`closest` looks up the DOM tree, at parents and ancestors, rather than at siblings. As the `input` element is a sibling of the `textarea` element, you need to look at siblings. To do that, you could use [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/), (assuming the `input` always directly follows the `textarea`... if not, you could use [`nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) or [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) with the appropriate selector)

```
$(this).next().removeAttr("disabled");
```